# How to convert php function return value to a wordpress slug?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a PHP function

```
<?php echo $current_user->membership_level->name?>
```

The output is this **Some Kind Of Category Name**.

I want to convert it to a Wordpress slug **some-kind-of-category-name**

To do that, I've chosen the $sług function = sanitize_title(::);

```
<?php echo $slug = sanitize_title("$current_user->membership_level->name"); ?>
```

However, I get the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string

Could you please help me, how should I write the php function? I'm new to PHP and I'm getting really frustrated with the code above.

Regards

Tom

Comment: For a slug, you may prefer [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<?php echo $slug = sanitize_title($current_user->membership_level->name); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove double quote:

```
echo $slug = sanitize_title($current_user->membership_level->name);
```

OR use like:

```
echo $slug = sanitize_title("{$current_user->membership_level->name}");
```